# URL not working due to hashtag ('#') special character present

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, url

I am trying to implement a "Share this on Facebook" functionality. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" title="Share this on Facebook"
                           href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{currentUrl}}"
                           onclick="openPopupWindow(this.href); return false;">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function openPopupWindow(url) {
window.open(url,'targetWindow',
    'toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, 
width=640, height=480');
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.currentUrl = document.URL;
```

I am using ui-sref to navigate between states and as a result, each URL that shows up in my browser will look something like this:

```
http:// hostName:port/#/stateName
```

That hashtag breaks the functionality I am trying to implement, meaning it will try to locate the page called **stateName** on Facebook. The resulting link of what I am trying to share becomes `http:// www.facebook.com/stateName` instead of `http:// hostName:port/#/stateName.`

My question is:

Is it possible to solve this without getting rid of the # in the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to encode the Hash within the URL with a `%23`

```
http:// hostName:port/%23/stateName
```

becomes

```
http:// hostName:port/#/stateName
```

Other encoding values can be found [here](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just build the URL manually or encode it?

```
$scope.currentUrl = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
```

Comment: Probably more future-proof too over the accepted solution...since you may end up with additional items to 'escape' down the road. But hey, whatever works for you!